# How to pull individual pieces of data from a JSON output String?

Tags: java, json, output

In Java, how would I pull the data for just the "data" section in the following JSON output?

> {"getuserhashrate":{"data":1425,"runtime":8.2659721374512,"version":"1.0.0"}}

json.get("data") does not work and gives the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["data"] not found.
>       at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:454)
>       at so4308554.JsonReader.main(JsonReader.java:40)

Comment: I would highly suggest a quick read of [json.org](http://json.org) to familiarize yourself with JSON. There are also numerous posts on SO regarding the topic.

Comment: You will notice that that output has a JSON object inside another JSON object. So, you should access the values by first accessing the getuserhasrate and move on from there. Again, just like @Brian Roach said, check out the docs at json.org

Comment: I would recommend using a JSON parser.

Answer (score 1):

You have a JSON object. It contains exactly one field: `getuserhashrate`

```
{"getuserhashrate": ... }
```

That field contains another JSON object which has its own fields ("data", "runtime", etc).

```
{"data":1425,"runtime":8.2659721374512, .. }
```

From looking at your stack trace, you're using the basic [json.org library](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/package-summary.html) (or the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html)).

You'd parse the JSON and get back the top-level object via:

```
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(myJsonString);
```

Then you'd get the object contained in the `getuserhashrate` field:

```
JSONObject data = root.getJSONObject("getuserhashrate");
```

Now you are able to access the fields of that object.

Answer (score 0):

JsonPath is a good tool to extract information from JSON

{"getuserhashrate":{"data":1425,"runtime":8.2659721374512,"version":"1.0.0"}}

```
String json = yourStringjson;
String data = JsonPath.read(json, "$.getuserhashrate.data");
```

*data will be 1425*

Just add the libs and it will be a useful tool if you dont want to create beans to have a full marshall

https://code.google.com/p/json-path/

Comment: tried this out, and am getting a lot of funky errors. Not so sure how to fix them because I am unfamiliar to the library.